# Button does not appear on IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, button, cross-browser, crossrider

I have an extension that adds a button to the browser and it work in Chrome. When I install the extension on Internet Explorer the button does not appear. What am I doing wrong? My code looks like this:

```
appAPI.ready(function() {
    appAPI.browserAction.onClick(function() {..});
});
```

Comment: What extension are you using?

Comment: add more code please

Answer (score 1):

To correctly initialize the button, you must add the button icon using [appAPI.browserAction.setResourceIcon](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.browserAction-method-setResourceIcon) as stated in the Crossrider API [docs](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.browserAction). Hence, first add an icon image (e.g. icon.png) to the extension's resources and set it as the icons button, as follows:

```
appAPI.ready(function() {
    appAPI.browserAction.setResourceIcon('icon.png');
    appAPI.browserAction.onClick(function() {..});
});
```

[**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified if your extension is visible in IE?

Does the IE console show any errors?

Here's the documentation I found in debugging issues in IE:

http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/guide/troubleshooting_ie